# how non existing hash key returns empty string?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, savon

Here is the exact problem;

```
$ hash
=> {:createAuthenticationTokenRequest=>{:playerSessionID=>"111"}}

$ hash[:attributes!]
=> ""  (here is the crazy result)

$ hash.class
=> Hash

$ hash.keys
=> [:createAuthenticationTokenRequest]
```

what is going on here? Am i not supposed to get nil for non existent hash keys ?

Detailed problem:

I am using savon to send a webservice request and getting "can't convert Symbol into Integer" error all the time, debugging the error with pry showed me that this line is getting executed as empty string which it shouldn't.

```
attributes = hash[:attributes!] || {}
```

Help me out here!

thanks in advance, cheers!

Update:
Answer for how the hash is created;

```
class Gyoku::Hash
  def self.iterate_with_xml(hash)
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
    attributes = hash[:attributes!] || {}
```

Update2:
This is the request i am sending

```
request(
      createAuthenticationTokenRequest: {
        playerSessionID: "111"
      }
    )
```

As i mentioned before this is savon gem code that gets executed. I tried to write the question as less boring as possible, and don't get why it gets downvoted :/

here is the source code that gets debugged.

https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku/blob/master/lib/gyoku/hash.rb

Comment: How was your hash created? It may have a default value (which is empty string)

Comment: I see no answer to how the hash is created. Is it a standard vanilla hash or your subclass?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think I need to go for sleep now.. :)) can't see things properly... :)))

Comment: The `hash` you have in pry where you're seeing `hash[:attributes!]` produce an empty string -- how did you create **that** `hash`?

Comment: `hash` either has a default value or `hash[:attributes!]` has been set to `""`. Carry on debugging, because there's nothing else we can deduce from this question.

Comment: @whizkid: Your edit for "how the hash is created" does not in fact show the hash creation. Can you please trace back to where `Hash.new` is called, by looking at the caller of `iterate_with_xml`, and up through callers  until you either have your own code or a library function that is creating the initial `Hash`

Answer (score 0):

i guess i deserved to be downvoted......

Don't do this in your code,

```
def default_request_parameters
  @default_request_parameters || Hash.new('')
end
```

Comment: Or rather "don't do this without knowing what you're doing".

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a hash like this
>
> way 1:
>
> new_hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = ""}
>
> new_hash['unknown_key']
>
> it returns
>
> => ""
>
> new_hash.keys
>
> => ['unknown_key']
>
> this adds 'unknown_key' key to the hash.
>
> way 2:
>
> hash2 = Hash.new("")
>
> hash2['unknown_key']
>
> it returns
>
> => ""
>
> but no keys are added.
>
> hash2.keys
>
> it returns
>
> => []

Comment: Are you quoting someone or using bad formatting? If quoting, you need to give proper attribution to the source of the quote. If you're saying it, please fix the formatting.

Comment: @theTinMan, i does not mean that at all, i mean that this is the part of ruby programming behavior, the programmer must have need this to  do in order to do achieve some functionality.

Comment: And I mean that your answer is formatted entirely like a quote. You need to fix that.